# Error 403 al modificar un perfil

Tags: php

Tengo un problema interesante. Tengo un formulario de perfil de usuario donde el mismo, modifica datos una vez que se registra. 
Toda la carpeta donde estan todos los archivos que manejan esta modificación de los datos del perfil, se llama "perfil" y tiene permiso 0755 que es el permiso por defecto que le da el hosting donde yo tengo contratado el servicio para alojar la página. 
Cuando lleno el formulario, paso los datos por el metodo post llamando a una página llamada "modificar.php". Ahí hago todo el proceso de grabacion.
Cuando doy el submit, me sale error 403

```
<form class="ui form attached fluid segment" role="form" action="modificar.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Tengo un htaccess que lo deshabilite para ver bien el error y efectivamente es error 403. Le cambie el nombre de la pagina destino, y lo mismo.
No me ocurre con otras paginas del proyecto en las que tambien envío fotografias a traves del post.
A Alguien le ha ocurrido esto ? 
Me pueden dar una mano para ver que debo revisar ?
Desde ya muchas gracias

el error que arroja es especificamente: 
https://www.sitio.com/forms/perfil/perfilusuario.phpwww.sitio.comXXX.XXX.XXX.XXXMozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36/forms/perfil/modificar.php403

---

ACTUALIZACION DE INFORMACION:

Cuando entro a modificar.php hace un proceso de verificacion del captcha de google. Acto seguido ejecuto lo siguiente. Proceso la imagen que traigo del perfil (si ingreso una foto nueva)

```
    $resultado = 0;
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $idusuario = $_POST['idusuario'];
    $nombreDestino = $idusuario . '.jpg';

    //BASADO EN JPEG
    if (isset($_FILES['fotoperfil']) && $_FILES['fotoperfil']['tmp_name']!=''){
        //Imagen original

        $old = getcwd(); // Conservo el directorio desde donde estoy accediendo
        chdir('../../users/');
        if  (file_exists($nombreDestino)){
            $do = unlink($nombreDestino);
            clearstatcache();
            if ($do != true) {
                echo "hubo un error al intentar borrar el archivo";
            }
        } // Vuelvo al directorio donde estaba  


        $rtOriginal=$_FILES['fotoperfil']['tmp_name'];

        $nombreDestino = $idusuario . '.jpg';

        //Crear variable
        $original = imagecreatefromjpeg($rtOriginal);

        //Ancho y alto máximo
        $max_ancho = 150; $max_alto = 150;

        //Medir la imagen
        list($ancho,$alto)=getimagesize($rtOriginal);

        //Ratio
        $x_ratio = $max_ancho / $ancho;
        $y_ratio = $max_alto / $alto;

        //Proporciones
        if(($ancho <= $max_ancho) && ($alto <= $max_alto) ){
            $ancho_final = $ancho;
            $alto_final = $alto;
        } else if (($x_ratio * $alto) < $max_alto){
            $alto_final = ceil($x_ratio * $alto);
            $ancho_final = $max_ancho;
        } else {
            $ancho_final = ceil($y_ratio * $ancho);
            $alto_final = $max_alto;
        }

        //Crear un lienzo
        $lienzo = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_final,$alto_final);

        //Copiar original en lienzo
        imagecopyresampled($lienzo,$original,0,0,0,0,$ancho_final, $alto_final,$ancho,$alto);

        //Destruir la original
        imagedestroy($original);

        //Crear la imagen y guardar en directorio upload/
        imagejpeg($lienzo,"../../users/" . $nombreDestino);
    }
```

Hice algunas correcciones en el código y ahora funciona localmente con el wamp pero cuando lo subo al servidor, no funciona. Me sigue arrojando el error 403. Ahora voy a probar eliminando toda la parte del codigo donde hago el borrado y la grabacion del archivo para identificar si ahi es donde esta el problema...
El error puede ser que sea porque la carpeta donde guardo las imagenes se llama "USERS" ? será un nombre reservado ?

Comment: Hola, primero que nada estas utilizando algun framework? recuerda subir el codigo necesario para poderte ayudar a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: No no estoy usando ningún framework. Uso semantic ui como capa de personalización gráfica...

Comment: Actualiza tu respuesta con el codigo PHP donde recibes la imagen.

Comment: @ByGroxD ahi coloque el codigo que se ejecuta en modificar.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamentablemente el error 403 se debía a que en el servicio de hosting tenían un tal modsecurity de apache habilitado. Cambiaron la configuración y adiós problemas

Comment: Coloca ésto como comentario y elimina la respuesta ya que sino un moderador lo hace y te restan puntos. Saludos!